# CSSTransition component's callbacks are not called in Cypress testing environment

Tags: cypress, reactcsstransitiongroup

I've been using this React CSSTransition component:

http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition

I'm adding Cypress tests. CSSTransition callbacks such as `onExited` and `onEntered` always run when I'm walking through my app in a regular browser (Chrome). But in the version of Chrome being automated by Cypress,  these callbacks are either never called or never executed.

I wonder if anyone else has run into this issue, or has some ideas about why it's happening, and how to fix it, or work around it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please provide code examples.

Comment: @eric99 I made a dummy react with nothing but CSS transition and Cypress to see if it would replicate. It didn't. Then I was able to replicate. The difference seems to be using cy.clock.

Answer (score 1):

It had to do with `cy.clock`. If you use `cy.clock` earlier in the test, you need to use `cy.tick`, or

```js
        cy.clock().then((clock) => {
            clock.restore()
        })
```